# DataGrid cannot update new row

Tags: apache-flex

I have the following function which add a item to the database and then return to the data grid. The data management method is PHP. and my problem is the database have recevied the new data but the datagrid dont have the new record.

Here is the simplify version of the code

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import spark.events.GridItemEditorEvent;

            protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                getAllUserResult.token = userService.getAllUser();

            }


            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                var user:User = new User();

                user.idUser = parseInt(idUserTextInput.text);
                user.userName = userNameTextInput.text;
                user.password = passwordTextInput.text;

                createUserResult.token = userService.createUser(user);

                userService.commit();


                //getAllUserResult.token = userService.getAllUser();
                //dataGrid.invalidateDisplayList();

                //var e:FlexEvent;
                //dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(e);

                //user.idUser=createUserResult.token.result as int;
                //dataGrid.dataProvider.addItem(user);

                this.currentState="State1";
            }
    </fx:Script>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>
    <s:State name="Add"/>
</s:states>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getAllUserResult"/>
        <userservice:UserService id="userService"
                                   fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                   showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <valueObjects:User id="user"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="createUserResult"/>

    </fx:Declarations>



<s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" includeIn="State1" x="95" y="10" width="961" height="505"
                creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" editable="true"
                gridItemEditorSessionSave="dataGrid_gridItemEditorSessionSaveHandler(event)"
                requestedRowCount="4" >
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="idUser" headerText="idUser"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="userName" headerText="userName"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="password" headerText="password"></s:GridColumn>

            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:typicalItem>
            <fx:Object idUser="idUser1" Name="Name1" password="password1"></fx:Object>
        </s:typicalItem>
        <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllUserResult.lastResult}"/>
    </s:DataGrid>

    <s:Button id="button" includeIn="Add" x="695" y="407" label="CreateUser"
              click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>


    <s:Form includeIn="Add" x="74" y="21" width="343" height="362">
            <s:FormItem width="200" label="IdUser">
                <s:helpContent >
                    <s:VGroup>
                        <s:Label width="76" height="42" text="Auto Generate"></s:Label>
                    </s:VGroup>
                </s:helpContent>
                <s:Label id="idUserTextInput" text="{user.idUser}"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="UserName" required="true">
                <s:TextInput id="userNameTextInput" text="{user.userName}"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="Password" required="true">
                <s:TextInput id="passwordTextInput" text="{user.password}"/>
            </s:FormItem>

    </s:Form>
```

I have tried serval method to debug (the commented function in the button_clickHandler), but, the result is still same.

Any other method I can try??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try refreshing dataprovider?

Comment: I had "//getAllUserResult.token = userService.getAllUser();" is the method I tried, not working.